Making a custom node for geometry node in Blender 4.1
I want to make a custom node in Blender 4.1
This is what I have so far but it doesn't seen to work as I can't find it.
import bpy 
 
# Custom node type 
class MyCustomNode(bpy.types.Node): 
    bl_idname = "MyCustomNodeType" 
    bl_label = "My Custom Node" 
    bl_icon = "NODE"
 
    def init(self, context): 
        self.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Input") 
        self.outputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Output") 
 
# Register and unregister functions 
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyCustomNode) 
 
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyCustomNodeTree) 
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    register() 

Eventually I want this node to do something but I want to get this right for now.
also I could prefer the node to appear in input/constant.
If someone could help me with that. I will appreciate it.

Geometry nodes are written in C++ not python so unless you're prepared to recompile Blender I think you're out of luck. There's a fairly old basic tutorial here.

Yeah I saw that but I was hoping that they would have a python version like for the shader nodes.
Thanks

I'm no expert but I don't beleive there's even a way of creating a shader node from scratch with python. The only comment I've seen about shader nodes is this one from Brecht who is a Blender developer.

Is there a way to create custom Node types or Nodes Categories using Python?

You can write OSL shader nodes, but this will limit you to using CPU. You can write custom nodes, but these will have to be used in the context of a new node editor, not an existing one.

In response to one of the comments: I’m not sure how much you can do, but I created a simple node that returns the square of the input, and it works in the shader editor.
import bpy 
 
# Custom node type 
class CustomSquareNode(bpy.types.Node):
    bl_idname = "CustomNodeType_Square"  # Unique identifier for the node
    bl_label = "Square Node"  # Name that will appear on the node in the editor
    bl_icon = 'EXPERIMENTAL'
 
    def init(self, context): 
        self.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Input") 
        self.outputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Output")

    def update(self):
        
        # Check if the input socket has a value
        if self.inputs["Input"].is_linked:
            # If there's a connection, use the connected value
            input_value = self.inputs["Input"].links[0].from_socket.default_value
        else:
            # If there's no connection, use the value in the input socket
            input_value = self.inputs["Input"].default_value
        
        # Perform the square calculation
        result = input_value ** 2
        
        # Set the output socket to the result
        self.outputs["Output"].default_value = result

def add_custom_node_to_menu(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("node.add_node", text="Square Node").type = CustomSquareNode.bl_idname

bpy.types.NODE_MT_add.append(add_custom_node_to_menu)


# Register and unregister functions 
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomSquareNode) 
 
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomSquareNode) 
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    register()

However, I was after something more than just the square of the input; that was only a test. My goal is to make a node that can read values from a CSV file, similar to how you can use an image. In geometry nodes, not the shader editor.

here's the problem: https://i.imgur.com/VoLlM7k.gif

I think making nodes in python is limited. (I don't know) anyway I wanted to do it in geometry nodes but in there the node doesn't do anything. At least in the shader do something sometimes, maybe with some tweaks can work properly all the time.
Anyway I trying to do something different about reading CVS files and get the values to be able to use them in blender
